Issue Accessing Azure Cloud Services via Rest API
I'm attempting to execute REST API calls on an azure cloud service.  I'm using Postman to test.  I've successfully retrieve the bearer token and am passing this to the request.
However, it seems no matter what I do, I'm getting an error.
<Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Code>ForbiddenError</Code>
    <Message>The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and 

is associated with this subscription.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/cloudservices/rest-list-cloud-services
I have no issues executing requests on other api calls (other than cloud services) such as getting a list of resource groups, etc.  It only seems to affect the cloud services api calls.
Any help would be appreciated.

Try this query https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames?api-version=2016-04-01 and let me know this will work for you or not

This worked.  I'm trying to use the get-package functionality of the rest api.  I don't see an equivalent through this.  Are you aware of any?

Initially, When I tried to reproduce same in my enviornment, I got same error:

To resolve this error, Need to upload certificate(.cer) at Azure Subscription Level.
To generate Self-Signed Certificate use below powershell script:
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "<your_domain_name" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\CurrentUser\My"

$cert.Thumbprint

Export-PfxCertificate -Cert "cert:\CurrentUser\My\{Thumbprint}" -FilePath "C:\path\to\certificate.pfx" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "yourpassword" -Force -AsPlainText

Export-Certificate -Cert "cert:\CurrentUser\My\{Thumbprint}" -FilePath "<file_path>\certificate.cer"



After generating self-signed certificate:
Go to Subscriptions --> Settings --> Management Certificates --> Upload Certificate

Now, generated access token by ensuring aud:https://management.core.windows.net/

Using above generated access token in  below endpoint for listing cloud services:
Request Header :  x-ms-version : 2009-10-01

GET https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices

Response:

NOTE: Header: x-ms-version should be set to 2009-10-01 or higher.
Reference:
List Cloud Services

This got me mostly through.  Works for the list resources.  However, now I'm receiving the following error when using the get-package call: BadRequestParameter value 'https://.blob.core.windows.net/' specified for parameter 'ContainerUriString' is invalid.
